# DFS like algorithm to find single source shortest path

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I know DFS is not good choice to find shortest path from a source and BFS or dynamic programming solutions are better but i'm just interested in hypothetical situation of speed of particular algorithm.Let's say i have an undirected graph that looks just like 2-D array and i can move up, down left right on it and I choose cell in that array a[i][j] and start performing recursive algorithm like this below..

```
public static void dfs(int graph[][], int i, int j, int distance){
    //up right down left directions
    int dirs[][] = new int[][]{{-1, 0},{0, 1},{1, 0},{0, -1}};
    for(int dir[] : dirs){
         int new_i = i + dir[0];
         int new_j = j + dir[1];
         //out of bounds check
         if(new_i < 0 || new_i >= graph.length || new_j < 0 || new_j >= graph[0].length)
               continue;
         //if distance is less then previously found then change it and go deeper
         if(distance < graph[new_i][new_j]){
             graph[new_i][new_j] = distance;
             dfs(graph, new_i, new_j, distance + 1);
         }
    }
}
```

So let's say that graph array elements are filled with Integer.MAX_VALUE. And i choose particular g[i][j] set it to zero and perform dfs(g, i, j, 1). Since it's not normal dfs algorithm because it  has potential to visit the same node multiple times and changes the distance to shorter one so i don't know the worst time complexity. Intuition tells me that it is slow but I have no idea what would be the worst complexity of this?

Comment: Do you expect to obtain `graph[i][j]==Math.abs(i-i0)+Math.abs(j-j0)+1` for (i,j) != (i0,j0)?

Comment: Yes if you mean that i0 and j0 are starting points. Or to be more precise i think without +1 at the end.

Comment: by initially calling `dfs(g, i0, j0, 0)` you would get rid of the `+1`. As for the efficiency, it sounds rather bad because you will return to the same locations multiple times.

Comment: i'm not sure but i think if i set g[i0][j0] to zero first and then call dfs(g, i0, j0, 1) it will set 1 to neighbours so i don't think there is +1 but i might be wrong:D. And yes the complexity sounds bad but i really would just like to know how bad is it.

Comment: There are no walls or anything in this grid.  The shortest distance to any (x,y) is just |x-i0| + |j-y0|.  I don't think this is really what you want to ask.  The worst case for this algorithm is not going to be the same as the worst case with walls.

Comment: Matt even without any obstacles or walls this algortihm is still bad. For example when i just run a counter on how many times dfs was executed for the grid 25*25 and starting point g[2][2] i get 37158 calls and there are only 625 nodes.

Comment: >  call dfs(g, i0, j0, 1) it will set 1 to neighbours
Your right about that

Comment: And by the way Matt i really like your deleted comment. At least I know what is the complexity of this algorithm in different type of graphs. And maybe in this silly hypothetical situation is the same?

Comment: Heh, yeah, I answered the question I *wanted* you to be asking :).  In this case, though the time for an NxN grid will be O(N^3) at worst, since each cell can be reduced at most O(N) times.  That applies to the case with walls, too, so I guess it comes out the same.

Comment: It sounds logical but unfortunately i don't understand why cell can be reduced at most O(N) times.

Comment: Ok so the path cannot get bigger than N * N so maybe it cannot be reduced more than N * N times?

Comment: So maybe if the cell cannot be reduced more than N * N then the final complexity would be O(V * V) where V is the number of vertices and V = N * N in this grid like graph ? This is because each cell cannot be visited more than V times and there are V cells?

Comment: I have run this algorithm on an 8x8 grid, I'm getting 930 calls

Comment: Nice Maurice!. So that means that N^3 is to small complexity because 8^3 is 512. But V^2 is 64 * 64=4096 which is in the bounds.I think Matt wanted to say that complexity is N^4 because he hinted that cell cannot be reduced more than N times and he probably wanted to say N * N (number of nodes).When the algorithm start to go deeper he cannot go deeper than the number of nodes without  going back so the value of cell cannot get bigger than the number of nodes so the cell cannot be reduced more than the number of nodes because the value of the cell can be in between [0; number of nodes]

Comment: Not counting Integer.MAX_VALUE at the begining

Comment: But to be honest 930 calls is still closer to N^3 than N^4 so i dont know. Maybe the constant factor is around 2 and the complexity is N^3

Comment: But for 40X40 grid i get 624 890 calls and 40^3 = 64 000 and 40^4 = 2 560 000